# Newton's Method: Found a case where it doesn't work. Why?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, newton-raphson

So I was looking to use Newton's Method to evaluate $x^3-2*x+2 = 0$.
I noticed that I could plug in a negative number for $x_0$ and it worked but when I tried $x_0 = 0$ then my code started going crazy and did not find the root. Anyone know why this does this, and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$
x_{new} = x_{old} -\frac{x_{old}^3 -2x_{old} +2}{3x_{old}^2-2}
$$
First iterations with $x_0$
$$
x_{1} = 0 -\frac{2}{-2} = 1\\
x_2 = 1 -\frac{1}{1} = 0 = x_0
$$
Thus you hit a limit cycle (attractor) where the values will just repeat.

Comment: One should remark that this behavior is fairly typical: oscillations and divergence are common behavior for Newton iterations if the initial guess is too far from the actual root. In this case $0$ is actually on the wrong side of a local maximum, which can easily cause problems.

Comment: This is why I tend to use combinations to produce a robust root finder. Though i would of thought matlab would of implemented them.

Comment: Is Matlab's fzero function not robust?

Comment: fzero uses one of these hybrid type methods, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I would of thought so. It is a standard benchmark (or should be) for any mathematical programming language to have a fast and robust method. It's only when you start stepping into implementing your own does it get hairy. Though it's dependent on the task at hand which method I choose to implement. Also, the packaged root finders tend to have maximum interation (if the adaptive scheme doesn't kick in).

Answer (score 1):

Chinny84 is right, unfortunately the orbit produced by the Newton method with starting point $x_0=0$ is periodic in this case, and does not converge to the root of your polynomial.

I just would like to stress that the convergence of the Newton method is a really tricky issue, indeed, you can  produce fractals based on the convergence of this method applied to particular (bivariate) polynomials :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal

Comment: ... also univariate, but in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Newton's Method is not guaranteed to work for every initial point.  The immediate basin of attraction of the zero $p$, i.e. the largest open interval containing $p$ such that from every starting point in this interval the iteration converges to $p$, will have one of the following forms:

1. $(-\infty, \infty)$
2. $(-\infty, b)$ where $f'(b) = 0$
3. $(a,\infty)$ where $f'(a) = 0$
4. $(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ form a repelling two-cycle for Newton's method.

In this case we have case (2) with $b = -\sqrt{6}/3 = -.8164965809$ approximately.

Comment: Any source for the above assertions?